# NoSuchMethodError (org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger) when running program outside Eclipse

Tags: java, command-line-interface, slf4j, nosuchmethoderror

Each time I try to run a program which uses a SLFj4 logger (LoggerFactory.getLogger(myClass.class)) from the command line, I get a `NoSuchMethodError`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
```

The interesting thing is that I don't get this error when I run the same program inside Eclipse. There are no errors when compiling the code. And the method `getLogger` definitively exists in the corresponding class file in the classpath.

I tried the newest versions of SLF4j API and binding, but the error stills exists. I have added all relevant classes to the classpath (and there are no ClassNotFoundExceptions).

What can I try to do? What further information do you need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it a maven or ant project?

Comment: The project with the tiny program I want to run is a simple Java project without any build tools. But it uses some classes from projects that are using Maven.

Comment: I've found a simple workaround for my problem:

If I replace the Class parameter variant

    LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz);

with the String parameter variant

    LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz.getName());

everything works fine.
But still the question is: Why? I would be happy to hear an explanation for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using two dependencies which includes SLF4j, try to exclude from one of dependency and then try again.

Also make sure you are using same versions.